# Updating ManyToMany jointable class from GET with JSON symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

is this right?
when update ManyToMany relationed table!

1. remove all relation id from relation table
2. insert incoming data
3. flush

i think it is wrong way or what?